# Unable to return a response using return-response policy in Azure API management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, string-concatenation, policies

I have a condition like:
In the outbound I will check the response of the GET API which is where aAPI policies are there. If the body has a key with entityStatus which takes values 0 or 1, if 0 then output simple message else need to **send-request** to another API endpoint which is POST API.

I used API policies as below:

```
<set-variable name="id" value="" />
    <set-variable name="newRequest" value="@(context.Request.Body?.As<JObject> 
           (preserveContent: true))" />
    <choose>
     <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200 && 
     (int)context.Response.Body?.As<JObject>(true)["entityStatus"] == 1)">
    <send-request mode="new" timeout="20" response-variable-name="id" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>@($"https://api.dev/external/workrequest/wr")</set-url>
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","scheme param"))</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>@{ var document = (JObject)context.Variables["newRequest"];
                      return document?.ToString();
                    }</set-body>
    </send-request>
    <return-response response-variable-name="id">
        <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>@((((IResponse)context.Variables["id"]).Body.As<JObject>()).ToString())</set-body>
    </return-response>
</when>
<when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200 && (int)context.Response.Body?.As<JObject>(true)["entityStatus"] == 0)">
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="500" reason="VOID" />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value></set-header>
        <set-body>The record is void</set-body>
     </return-response>
</when>
<otherwise />
```

The response it returned was good when entityStatus was 0 but when entityStatus is 1 it was returning a 400 error. The error is like:

```
{
"type": "https://httpstatuses.io/400",
"title": "Bad Request",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "00-317b53ba7a76f19b6153ca6ab14c5190-e9c27cf9162e2414-00"
 }
```

I just need the response from the POST API which I am sending the request to and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution, I was using below variable that will take request body:

`<set-variable name="newRequest" value="@(context.Request.Body?.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true))" />`

I changed it by using:

`set-variable name="newRequest" value="@(context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true))" />`